# Oracle Apex 5.1 Interactive Grid change column type by row

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

In APEX 5.1 interactive grid I want to change the type of column (Text field or Select list) based on the content of the current row. 
Actually it's a key-value editor on a two column wide table. Values on some keys are free to edit, others are restricted to specific set of values.
Is it possible to do with interactive grid?

Comment: This seems to be an acceptable use case, but I do not think apex has some dynamic action to change the column type according to the value of the data row. I also can not imagine another more efficient way of doing this in terms of the UI.  But if you can, I would recommend doing it another way.

Comment: I have the same requirement. Have you found a way to solve this by any chance?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way (I did not find). Finally I used classic report, added items in the sql query and also implemented custom processing logic.